# Cannot use sidebar android in Card view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a Card View which displays the list of items. I tried aligning the cards one below another and I was not able to implement it. Another problem I'm facing now is that I cannot access the sidebar items. I'm able to see the sidebar by swiping to right and the icon for sidebar is missing on the nav bar.

Here is the code snippet:

*activity_top_ten_items.xml*

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_teams"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <include layout="@layout/topteam_recycler" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

*app_bar_teams.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.neonsec.ctftime.ctf_timemobile.MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_top_ten_teams"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="667dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="59dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

*content_top_10_items.xml*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_album_radius">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/album_cover_height"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:textSize="@dimen/album_title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tpoints"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tname"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:textSize="@dimen/songs_count" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To aligning the cards one below another you need to use a RecyclerView List with Cards. That would be a list of CardViews one below the other. Take a look on this: https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/material-design/android-cardview-tutorial/  , or this: http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-cardview-example/
 or this one to https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465

The *sidenav* items can be found here: `res/menu/activity_main_drawer.xml`. Make shure you have defined items there.

The button on the nav_bar for the sidenav is created programatically on your controller this way:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
```

See: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Hope it solve!!